# How can I format my returned url so that it conforms to my desired routing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

In my Kendo treeview HTML I have got this:

```
transport: {
    read: {
        url: function (options) {
            return kendo.format("http://localhost:51447/api/ProductID/", options.CourseID)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to format the resulting url from

```
http://localhost:51450/api/ProductID/?ProductID=1
```

to this format

```
http://localhost:51450/api/ProductID/1
```

My question is how do I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :You can make use of `replace()` available in javascript, see below

```js
var url = "http://localhost:51450/api/ProductID/?ProductID=1";
    url = url.replace("?ProductID=","");
    alert(url);
```

Comment: Bhushan Kawadkar I am  sure your solution would work if the url was fixed, but in this case where it is being 'computed' it has failed

Comment: I thought of that you cannot change code in kendo treeview but getting returned this url somewhere in your code (though it is computed runtime). You can use above solution where you are getting this original url. Just store url in a variable and apply `.replace()`

Comment: Finally your suggestion put me on the path to solving my problem. Thanks Bhushan

Comment: Great !! Happy to help you :)